# How to override a function that displays the user login block?

Tags: blocks, theming, users

I'm trying to override the function user_login_block so that the links do not appear. I'm doing it by declaring two functions, but nothing seems to work. Here is the code:

```
function bartik_modificado_theme() {
return array(
'user-login-block'=>array('arguments'=>array('form'=>NULL)));   
}
```

As I'm trying to modify the theme bartik, I put this function (also in the template.php):

```
function bartik_modificado_user_login_block($form) {
unset($form['links']['#markkup']);
return drupal_render($form);    
}
```

I'm new to drupal and I simply don't know why this isn't working. I am simply unsetting one of the variables in the original user_login_block function. I also tried copying the entire function and edited it, but nothing happened. Can someone point out what I'm missing please?

I've been playing around with the code and now I see I made two mistakes: first, the form id in the first piece of code I posted is 'user_login_block' with underscores, not dashes, and second, the variable I want to change is `$form['links']['#markup']`with one k, not two. But now the page stays forever loading until it gives me an error of maximum execution time. I'm thinking this is because I'm using drupal_render. ¿What function must I use to render the form, or still I ask what is going on? Please help.

This is the code updated:

```
function bartik_modificado_theme() {
return array(
'user_login_block'=>array('arguments'=>array('form'=>NULL)));   
}
```

And the call to the block function:

```
function bartik_modificado_user_login_block($form) {
unset($form['links']['#markup']);
$form['submit']['#value']=t('ir');
//$output.=drupal_render($form);
return drupal_render($form);    
}
```

Comment: Could you update your question with your updated code?

Comment: @Jayendra Kainthola Thank you for addressing my code, as I said I don't know what's wrong as everywhere I've searched seems to suggest that the way I'm doing it is correct, but whenever I use the `drupal_render` function the page throws me a bunch of notices that say `Notice: Undefined index: render element en devel_themer_theme_twin() drupal`. I've tried with `drupal_render_children`with the same output.

Comment: Are you using drupal 6 or drupal 7?

Comment: I'm thinking I should use `$hooks` as it seems to be the standard way to add functionality, though I don't fully understand the concept of hooks. I've read in this site that I might use something like `function mytheme_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
   $hooks['user_login_block'] = array(
     'template' => 'templates/user-login-block',
     'render element' => 'form',
   );` But then I wonder if there's any other configuration I should use.

Comment: I'm using drupal 7

Comment: I think I should use the hook concept because that seems to be the problem with the notice that php is giving me. From the comments in "theme.inc" I read that the variable `render element` is `'render element': The renderable element for this theme hook as defined
 *     in hook_theme()` but I don't understand how to declare a hook for the theme.

Comment: I have checked this and its working if we created template for 'user_login_block' form.

Comment: What does it mean create template for user_login_block form, does it mean I shouldn't place the functions in the template.php but rather in another user_login_block.tpl.php?

Comment: I have never tried with function in `template.php` file. I am looking into this and if I found anything, I will let you know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Drupal 7, we use `variables` array keys instead of `arguments` key.

In `bartik_modificado_theme` function, we should use `render element` as `form`.

> render element: (required if "variables" not present) A string that is
>   the name of the sole renderable element to pass to the theme function.
>   The string represents the name of the "variable" that will hold the
>   renderable array inside any optional preprocess or process functions."

Code snippets in `template.php` in theme directory.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme
 */

function themename_theme() {

  return array(
    'user_login_block'=> array(
        'render element' => 'form',
        'template' => 'user-login-block',
      )
    );
}
```

I have created new `tpl` file `user-login-block.tpl.php` in theme directory.

Code snippets in `user-login-block.tpl.php` file.

```
unset($form['links']['#markup']);
print drupal_render_children($form);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I did that, though I didn't know which themes directory to save the file at, so it throwed me a bunch of errors about file user-login-block.tpl.php not found for inclusion, so after correcting this I finally have no errors, but the html inside `$forms['links']['#markup']`is still showing. Don't know what I misunderstood, I'm trying to get rid of the links that create new users accounts and request for a new password. Sorry for insisting but can you explain me in plain english what the user-login-block.tpl.php file is supposed to do?

Comment: Thank you, I finally got it! I was trying to keep wrapping the code snippet you posted inside the `function bartik_modificado_user_login_block()`That's why I saw the links still showing. Using the bare code finally got rid of the links. Again, thanks for a clear and well pointed explanation.

Comment: @gerardoflores, Thanks for your appreciation. `tpl` file should be in your active theme directory.